# Getting portion of an html string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable named `response`. This is the response from an ajax call. This variable has the following content:

```
<table id="ListCompanies" class="zebra-striped">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Nom de la societe</th>
        <th>Ville</th>
        <th>Rue</th>
        <th width="70"><a class="btn primary small createCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Create">[+] Nouvelle societe</a> </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
        <tr id="13">
            <td>INDUSTRIAL DEFENDER INC</td>
            <td>FOXBOROUGH</td>
            <td>Chestnut Street</td>

            <td nowrap>                                    
                <a class="btn small editCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Edit/13" id="13">Modifier</a> 
                <a class="btn small deleteCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Delete/13" id="13">Supprimer</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="14">
            <td>INC CRANE NUCLEAR</td>
            <td>GEORGIA KENNESAW</td>
            <td>cobb International Blvd</td>

            <td nowrap>                                    
                <a class="btn small editCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Edit/14" id="14">Modifier</a> 
                <a class="btn small deleteCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Delete/14" id="14">Supprimer</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>

</table>



<a href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/RowsList?page=3" id="LoadMoreLink">Load more</a>
```

`alert($("tbody", response).html());` gives me:

```
        <tr id="13">
            <td>INDUSTRIAL DEFENDER INC</td>
            <td>FOXBOROUGH</td>
            <td>Chestnut Street</td>

            <td nowrap>                                    
                <a class="btn small editCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Edit/13" id="13">Modifier</a> 
                <a class="btn small deleteCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Delete/13" id="13">Supprimer</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="14">
            <td>INC CRANE NUCLEAR</td>
            <td>GEORGIA KENNESAW</td>
            <td>cobb International Blvd</td>

            <td nowrap>                                    
                <a class="btn small editCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Edit/14" id="14">Modifier</a> 
                <a class="btn small deleteCompany" href="/PLATON/Admin/Company/Delete/14" id="14">Supprimer</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

That's ok for me.

How can I get the link at the bottom `#LoadMoreLink` from the response variable?

I tried:

```
alert($("#LoadMoreLink",response));
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `response` contains 2 "parent" elements, the `<table>`, and the `<a>`.  `$(response)` creates a jQuery object with 2 elements.  To get the one you want, try this:

```
$(response).filter('#LoadMoreLink')
```

`.find` doesn't work here, as `.find` only searches children, not the "parent" elements themselves.  You need to use `.filter` to search for the "parent" element.

(By "parent" element, I mean the element that's actually in the jQuery object).

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction. $(response).filter('#LoadMoreLink')[0].outerHTML gives me what I want. Question: why do I need to add [0].outerHTML ?? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato You need the `[0]` because jQuery selections are special arrays of DOM elements, not the DOM elements themselves. Alternatively just use `.html()` to get the HTML.

Comment: @Bronzato: The `[0]` gets the native DOM element from the jQuery object, and `outerHTML` gets you the element itself, whereas `.html()` (which is `innerHTML` gets you the contents of the element.

Comment: @Bronzato: What are doing with this element?   Chances are you don't need to use `outerHTML`, you can just use the jQuery object.  For example: if you were appending this element, you could just do `$('#someDiv').append($(response).filter('#LoadMoreLink'))`.

Comment: I need to get the anchor link from the response variable in order to replace the actual anchor on the page. So here is what I do: var updatedLink = $(response).filter('#LoadMoreLink')[0].outerHTML; $('#LoadMoreLink').replaceWith(updatedLink); What do you think?

Comment: @Bronzato: The `[0].outerHTML` isn't needed here.  You can just do: `var updatedLink = $(response).filter('#LoadMoreLink');  $('#LoadMoreLink').replaceWith(updatedLink);`.

Comment: Thank you very much Rocket! Your help was precious.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a", response).filter("[id='LoadMoreLink']")
```

Should be what you need.  I think the normal search is failing because jQuery tries to access the DOM hash of elements with IDs, which "#LoadMoreLink" is not in (having not been loaded into the DOM yet).

Comment: It doesn't matter if the element is in the DOM or not, `#ID` will act the same.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works out then simply load the response in a hidden div and then retrieve $("#LoadMoreLink")